# Why do we use a voltage divider to measure the voltage of a thermistor?

Tags: analog, sensor, voltage-divider, thermistor

Can someone explain to me when and why I should use a voltage divider when I design a circuit?

Comment: When you need to divide a voltage?  Seriously, this is a pretty broad question.  You may or may not use one to measure the voltage of a thermistor or for a thousand other reasons.  Show us a specific example circuit and ask a specific question about it so we can focus on that to start.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you clarify your question: any divider in any circuit? Or specifically thermistors? What other methods could you think of?

Comment: You don't need to use a voltage divider. Just pick the method that is easiest for the accuracy you need. Also you are not really interested in the voltage of a thermistor either. You are interested in the resistance of the thermistor. Some methods might use the voltage as a proxy for the resistance, but others may not and just because they don't does not invalidate them.

Answer (score 1):

A thermistor is a variable resistor. Its resistance value is based on the temperature it is measuring - higher temperature lowers its resistance, lower temperature raises it.

The simplest and cheapest way to measure the value of a resistor in a circuit is to use a voltage divider circuit. By providing a known voltage level and using just one extra component, a resistor, you can get the resistance of the thermistor - and thus the temperature reading - with just an analog voltage reading. This is done by measuring the voltage in between the thermistor and the resistor and plugging it into the voltage divider equation with the thermistor resistance as your only unknown.

The body of your question does not exactly match with your title, which is what I answered. If you are still confused please edit your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage dividers don't measure anything. Thermistors have a resistance that varies in a somewhat predictable way with temperature. If you have a general-purpose ADC it likely measures voltage. A cheap one will likely measure voltage as a fraction of the power supply (in other words, the power supply voltage is the reference), better ones may have an external or internal voltage reference other than the power supply.

So if you want to convert resistance to voltage, in particular one that is a fraction of the ADC reference voltage, the simplest way is with a voltage divider connected from the ADC reference to ground, in which the thermistor is all or part of one of the resistors.

You can then calculate an estimate of the thermistor temperature, either directly from the measured ADC count via an equation or a look-up table, or indirectly by calculating the thermistor resistance and applying the appropriate equation such as Steinhart-Hart, or perhaps a cubic spline.

That said, common thermistors are very nonlinear and this simple approach may be inadequate for wide temperature ranges. An often better approach is to use an ADC that provides a digital output ratiometric to a reference resistance rather than a reference voltage and has a large dynamic range (in other words there is still plenty of resolution when the thermistor is (say) 1/10 or 10x the nominal resistance), but that's outside the scope of this answer.

Another factor that needs to be considered is self-heating.